# What is the relation between this vector triple product identity and commutators over rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, vector-spaces, lie-algebras

There is a well-known identity for $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b},\mathbf{c}\in\mathbb{R}^3$ sometimes called the "Back of the Cab" identity $$\mathbf{a}\times (\mathbf{b}\times \mathbf{c}) = \mathbf{b}(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{c}) - \mathbf{c}(\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{b})$$
and recently we used in a course involving some matrices the identity $$[a,bc] = [a,b]c + b[a,c]$$ where in a more general form than where we were working $a,b,c$ are any elements of a (potentially non-commutative) ring and $[a,b] = ab-ba$ is the commutator operation on the ring. My question is: **is there a relation between these two identities on a more fundamental level or are they simply two identities involving the letters $a,b,c$ which seem superficially similar?**

I understand that in the vector case there is a sign difference and also the cross product becomes a difference of dot-producted vectors (and the dot product produces a scalar rather than an another member of the domain like the commutator) so there is a noticeable difference. However, the idea that makes me believe they might be connected is that $[\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}] = \mathbf{a}\times \mathbf{b}$ and the commutator $[a,b]$ defined on any ring both are bilinear, are alternative and obey the Jacobi triple product identity and so make their respective domains into *Lie algebras*, but unfortunately I know little about Lie theory. Preferably any explanation of their connection will explain a little about how this fits into the context of Lie theory (given my lack of background knowledge here).

Comment: The cross product *can* be interpreted as a Lie bracket which further *can* be viewed as the commutator bracket of a certain associative multiplication. That multiplication, however, is something very different from the dot product -- as you say yourself, the dot product, already for (co)domain reasons, is not an associative product at all, and cannot even translate to one via possible identifications as above.

Comment: Note in particular that once we see the cross product as a Lie bracket, the LHS of your first identity becomes $[a,[b,c]]$. But if this bracket is the commutator from an associative multiplication, then this expression becomes $=abc-aca-bca+caa$ which differs from the RHS of either of your equations.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: I too had actually thought about these same things but was hoping that someone would just magically look at it from an even more general (categorical even?) perspective and tell me that they were actually the same from fifty thousand feet. Ah, when you follow your nose like this, you win some and you lose some! I'll leave the question open but with little hope.